# Pandas - How can I identify groups of data where two values in a column occur in a particular order?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with an ID, a Timestamp, and a Value. There are multiple rows per ID, and it is sorted by ID and Timestamp ascending. I need to identify the IDs where two values - 'A' and 'B' - occur any two rows, per ID, in that order. For example:-

```
ID       Timestamp      Value

001      00:01          A
001      00:02          B
001      00:03          B

002      00:01          B
002      00:02          A
002      00:03          B

003      00:01          B
003      00:02          A
003      00:03          A
```

Above, ID 001 and 002 qualify because A precedes B somewhere in the ID group. ID 003 doesn't qualify because A never precedes B.

Each group of IDs will contain at least one 'A' and one 'B', so I know if the 'A' comes first then it will qualify. However, if the 'B' comes first there are no such guarantees.

I have tried using idxmin to locate the first occurrence of each value and compare positions but I can't get it to work with a groupby. I am pained to even contemplate using a loop to circumvent my shortcoming here, but I can do so if necessary - however it seems to me that there must be a proper pythonic way to approach this, I just don't know what it is.

Any help or suggestions are hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sort, shift one column ahead. Then check row-wise

Comment: What  will be the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> df.sort_values("Timestamp") \           # mandatory for shift
      .groupby("ID")["Value"] \             # group by 'ID'
      .apply(lambda x: any(x > x.shift()))  # search B > A

ID
001     True
002     True
003    False
Name: Value, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `groupby` and check that the first occurrence of `'A'` is less than the last occurrence of `'B'`:

```
>>> df.groupby('ID')['Value'].apply(lambda x: list(x).index('A') <
                                    len(x) - 1 - list(x)[::-1].index('B'))
ID
001     True
002     True
003    False
Name: Value, dtype: bool
```

But I like Corralien's answer for being easier to read and using more of the pandas builtins!

Comment: Tom, many thanks for answering - what you've provided above is pretty much where I think I would have ended up (after another lengthy stint on Google) by doing the search/comparison part manually after the groupby - I accepted Corralien's answer for the same reason you stated above, but yours is absolutely useful too. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can also check if there are consecutive letters after `groupby` and joining them in a string. This will work for any letter, so having `CDA` would return `True` since `C` and `D` are consecutive letters.

```
def check(word):
    word = word.upper()
    for i in range(len(word) - 1):
        if (ord(word[i]) + 1) == ord(word[i + 1]):
            return True
    return False

>>> df.groupby("ID")["Value"].apply(lambda x: check("".join(x))))
    ID
    001     True
    002     True
    003    False
    Name: Value, dtype: bool
```